# I can't figure the issue with a stacktrace error

Tags: android, stack-trace

I am apparently having an issue with 1 activity on a Samsung Nexus in an app and I can't understand what is actually causing the the issue.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=244; index=1753
at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:168)
at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:204)
at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:281)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:140)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:80)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:59)
at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:5901)
at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5741)
at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6098)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1196)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:318)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the Activity that my customer is telling me is causing the problem. This is the ONLY problem.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;



public class Protocols03_04Activity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.protocols03_04);



    }
    //Options Menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.optmenu, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.medcom_optmenu_item).setIntent(new Intent(this, CallMedcom.class));
        menu.findItem(R.id.dispatch_optmenu_item).setIntent(new Intent(this, CallDispatch.class));
        menu.findItem(R.id.settings_optmenu_item).setIntent(new Intent(this, ProtocolsSettingsActivity.class));
        menu.findItem(R.id.mmenu_optmenu_item).setIntent(new Intent(this, ProtocolsMMenuActivity.class));
        menu.findItem(R.id.gps_optmenu_item).setIntent(new Intent(this, GPSActivity.class));
        menu.findItem(R.id.search_optmenu_item).setIntent(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have tried to recreate the issue, but I am not able. I tried on 2 different Motorola phones.

Comment: Thank you somuch djmedic... Your question saved me. I've the same kind of issue.

Answer (score 18):

Seems to be a known bug with TextView. Check similar issues [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35466) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35412)

There is mention of the galaxy in the post. The first issue is marked for future release, the second seemed to have been fixed.

UPDATED

djmedic has found a workaround [here](https://gist.github.com/3424004)

Comment: Thank you. Those links were helpful. I found a workaround but how do I implement it. It is at https://gist.github.com/3424004 . Is it a separate Activity and I call it? If so how do you call it? If it is to go into my actual Activity, I had errors.

Comment: You should test that code by replacing the TextView in your layouts with the JellyBeanSpanFixTextView. It's not an Acitivity, it's a custom TextView. So save JellyBeanSpanFixTextView somewhere, like com.myproject.mycustomtextview. [Here](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com.au/2010/05/android-custom-textview.html) is a tutorial I found to use a custom view in your layout. In particular, look at step 3, where it is using the fully qualified name to reference the custom view.

Comment: rlay3 Thankyou somuch for your answer. It saved me. Thanks a lot for the explanation for how to use the class.

Answer (score 5):

Had to same Problem after Updating Android Studio (or the sdk..). I could fix it by setting the inputType of the EditText.

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Answer (score 1):

I Had The same problem. Its not only an issue on jellyBean. It has to do with a text view adding span tags to html converted plain text causing an indexOutOfBounds exception. There is a workaround at this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35466).

Replace your text view with this custom textView. If the span tag issue arrises, this catches it and instead displays the content in plain text.

```
public class PatchedTextView extends TextView {
public PatchedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
public PatchedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public PatchedTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    try{
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        setText(getText().toString());
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
@Override
public void setGravity(int gravity){
    try{
        super.setGravity(gravity);
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        setText(getText().toString());
        super.setGravity(gravity);
    }
}
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    try{
        super.setText(text, type);
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        setText(text.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I had problems with the most voted answer. This worked great for me =)

Answer (score 0):

My experience may help to those pals, who don't want to add custom TextView to their projects.

First, I could reproduce this error in the Android emulator (4.1.2 , API 16).
After this I decided to figure out what is causing this error. Obviously - some formatting (which
causes "spans" to be created). It turned out that in my case it was enough to replace in two places e.g. this:

`\"<b>@username</b>\"`

with this:

`\"@username\"`