# EditText in ListView App Crashes

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have 2 listView on the same activity on of them have a EditText in every row.

> 1st problem : whenever i try and write something in the EditText of a
>   row the text either doesn't show or comes in a weird language.
>
> 2nd : when i am done with writing "which is not working" if i press
>   the back button so the keyboard disappears the app crashes.

on the other hand if i pressed on the EditText so the keyboard appears and pressed back without writing anything it works fine..

thanks.

CustomAdapter

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
        final OrderHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(l, null);

            holder  = new OrderHolder();

            holder.id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.oid);
            holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.oname);
            holder.price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.oprice);
            holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.oorder);
            holder.quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            holder.customise = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.customize);



            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            holder = (OrderHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }

        holder.id.setText(getId(getItem(position)));
        holder.name.setText(getName(getItem(position)));
        holder.price.setText("£ " + getPrice(getItem(position)));
        holder.customise.setText("");

        if(pos.containsKey(position))
        {
            holder.customise.setText(pos.get(position));                 

        }

                holder.quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                  HashMap<String, String> map = getItem(position);


              if(v.getId() == R.id.order)
             {

                  if ( orderList.contains(getItem(position)) ){
                      System.out.println("item :" +getItem(position));
                      //holder.quantity.setText("q");
                      int foo = Integer.parseInt(map.get(TAG_QUANTITY).toString());

                      map.put(TAG_QUANTITY, "" + (foo-1));
                      if((foo-1)==0)
                      {
                          orderList.remove(getItem(position));
                      }

                  }


                  ((MyOrderAdapter)  list1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                  ((MyOrderAdapter)  list11.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                          Float fo = Float.parseFloat(map.get(TAG_PRICE).toString());
                          Float total = Float.parseFloat(t.getText().toString());

                          //System.out.println("heeeeeeeeeeeeeere :" +fo);
                          t.setText(""+ String.format("%.2f", (total-fo)));
                  }
            }
          });
            holder.btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                      Float fo = Float.parseFloat((getItem(position).get(TAG_PRICE)).toString());
                      Float Quant = Float.parseFloat((getItem(position).get(TAG_QUANTITY)).toString());
                      Float total = Float.parseFloat(t.getText().toString());
                      //System.out.println("heeeeeeeeeeeeeere :" +fo);
                      orderList.remove(getItem(position));
                      t.setText(""+ String.format("%.2f", (total-(fo*Quant))));
                      ((MyOrderAdapter) list1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                      ((MyOrderAdapter) list11.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return false;
                }
            });



        holder.quantity.setText(getQuant(getItem(position)));
        return convertView;
    }
```

LOGCAT

```
04-07 13:16:24.126: I/Editor(16815): setup window support handles
04-07 13:16:24.126: I/Editor(16815): setup window support handles
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1832)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1809)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:759)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:910)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:414)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:293)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:267)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:952)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.text.Layout.getLineWidth(Layout.java:918)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.TextView.desired(TextView.java:6191)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6257)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.TableRow.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableRow.java:247)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:114)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1847)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1762)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1318)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1633)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4372)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1644)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.TableRow.onLayout(TableRow.java:123)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4372)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4372)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4372)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4372)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4372)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4372)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4372)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4372)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1984)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1805)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1105)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4462)
04-07 11:52:33.618: E/AndroidRuntime(16268):    at android.view.Choreograph
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running on SDK level 16? [It may be related to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849676/i-cant-figure-the-issue-with-a-stacktrace-error).

Also make sure you're not accidentally providing resource id into the TextView's `setText()`:

```
holder.id.setText(getId(getItem(position)));
```

Without seeing your code, `getId()` may be returning an int, whereas you probably want to specify its result as a String:

```
holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(getId(getItem(position))));
```

Comment: im returng a string with getId
`public String getId(HashMap<String, String> item){
       return item.get(TAG_ID).toString();
      }`

Comment: What about `getName()` and `getQuant()`?

Comment: they are all returning strings, This listView was working fine until i added the editText. I have an assumption but not sure. my listView is Included from another view and it is located at the bottom of the screen when the keyboard pops up it move all the component up with. I am wondering if the may cause any problem to the listView. if it might it is? is there any fix..one more thing the whole view is on FrameLayout..not sure if all that can help

Comment: Yes, indeed; upon reviewing, it appears to have nothing to do with the text contents of the TextView. I was a bit hasty. It instead seems that the dimensions of the TextView are somehow causing your woes. Perhaps the dimensions are zero?

Comment: Are you running on SDK level 16? [It may be related to this problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849676/i-cant-figure-the-issue-with-a-stacktrace-error)

Comment: i think it is the same problem, regarding SDK is level 16 yes

Comment: You may want to try one of the workarounds suggested either [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12849770/154306) or [from the comments to issue #35466](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35466). I'm curious if it indeed resolves your problem, as your stack trace appears doesn't appear to be related to spannables.

Comment: actually to add there was a part in my logcat that show spannable.StringBuilder cannot be zero

Comment: i found the fix. in that answer 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13696084/2040750)
it was the EditText input that had the problem after i changed it to
`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`

Comment: Great! Thanks for accepting my answer, but you should really post your comment as an answer and accept that.