# IndexOutOfBoundsException at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1774)

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

In my application one of user sometimes get error and application crashing. User send me log:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
 at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1774)
 at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1747)
 at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:164)
 at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:204)
 at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:281)
 at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:332)
 at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:176)
 at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6089)
 at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5987)
 at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6344)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4826)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15479)
 at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1847)
 at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
 at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
 at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1330)
 at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1600)
 at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2300)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1388)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onLayout(CustomViewAbove.java:481)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14061)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4374)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1807)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4454)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As I see, error occur not in my code, but in android code. But user say that error occur in my application only. How can I fix it? How to understand cause of this crashing?

Comment: Whats com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove?  R u using some other library?

Comment: Yes, it using this library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/slidingmenu

Comment: Known bug in TextView, solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12849770/2910492).

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by removing textAllCaps

```
android:textAllCaps="true"
```

My code is

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the **append** function to add text in Textview or EditText remove that and instead of that use **setText** function

Wrong -> `textView.append("sample")`

Right -> `textView.text = textView.text.toString().plus("sample")`