# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException in TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm getting:

```
1-27 13:47:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 13:47:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1070): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
01-27 13:47:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1777)
01-27 13:47:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:747)
01-27 13:47:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:898)
01-27 13:47:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:414)
01-27 13:47:35.569: E/AndroidRuntime(1070):     at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:293)
```

I tried the jellybeanspanfixtextview given in ([I can't figure the issue with a stacktrace error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849676/i-cant-figure-the-issue-with-a-stacktrace-error/21389971#21389971)) still getting a crash. 
I have a few - textview and edittext next to each other(horizontal layouts)- in my vertical linear layout. attempting typing into any of these ediittexts' crashing. Is there any know issue with edittext and textview sitting next to each other?? (its a bit cramped in the layout:))

for eg 
          TextView     : EditText
          "Text A": Enter text for A

i have no such problem in a different layout where I have textview followed by edittext

for eg 
          TextView
          EditText

```
      "Text A"
      Enter text for A
```

Appreciate the response

(even when i change to one after the other i have problems with this view (a

```
15:38:19.910: E/InputEventReceiver(1644): Exception dispatching input event.
01-27 15:38:19.910: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1644): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
01-27 15:38:20.290: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1644): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
01-27 15:38:20.290: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1644):   at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1777)
01-27 15:38:20.290: E/MessageQue)
```

so it could be something else i'm doing wrong in this view view

COMPLETE EXCEPTION LOG

```
1-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1777)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:747)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:898)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:414)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:293)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:852)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:830)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:805)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:795)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:5121)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocusInAbsoluteDirection(FocusFinder.java:232)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:163)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:94)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:668)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:670)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:670)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:670)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:670)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:670)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:6392)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:5627)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1120)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1281)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.viewClicked(InputMethodManager.java:1432)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.TextView.viewClicked(TextView.java:8607)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7629)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7384)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
01-27 15:38:20.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1644):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.
```

Comment: Do you have any listeners on these `EditText`s?

Comment: You should post the entire exception, as I think you ommited some important parts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849676/i-cant-figure-the-issue-with-a-stacktrace-error/12849770#12849770

Comment: yes i have an addTextChangedListener for each of the edittexts

Comment: is there a problem in using addTextChangedListener for multiple edittexts ? at the moment I have 7 edittexts(different fields) and addTextChangedListener  for each one. should i be changing to onFocusChange or something

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135222/android-textview-gives-indexoutofboundsexception-textline-handlerun

Answer (score 0):

i had  style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle" in my EditText fields ,that seemed to be causing the problem.