# Android TextView gives IndexOutOfBoundsException TextLine.handleRun

Tags: android

I'm getting this exception from a while ago I couldn't find anything helpful from the stack trace, Crashlytics reporting it that happening on Android 8 and 9

**here is the stack trace:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: measureLimit (54) is out of start (55) and limit (54) bounds
       at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:989)
       at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:500)
       at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:337)
       at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:272)
       at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:1370)
       at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:519)
       at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:292)
       at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:7765)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20370)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19315)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20373)
       at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.draw(NestedScrollView.java:1888)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19315)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
       at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1246)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4385)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4385)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4385)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4385)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4385)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4385)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4405)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4385)
       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:800)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3494)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3281)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2816)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1785)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7825)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

so the stack trace does not provide me with which `TextView` is happening I'm logging the screen that the crash happens in it and this screen has many `TextView` and I searched for that the whole web I couldn't see an answer.

**Update**

I'm suspicious in this code it draws a rounded background to a phone number in the `TextView`

```
public class RoundedBackgroundSpan extends ReplacementSpan implements LineHeightSpan {

    private static int CORNER_RADIUS = 8;
    private int backgroundColor = 0;
    private int textColor = 0;
    private int backgroundTranspernt;
    private float mTextSize = UIUtils.spToPx(16);

    private static final float PADDING_X = UIUtils.dp2px(4);
    private static final float PADDING_Y = UIUtils.dp2px(2);
    private static final float MAGIC_NUMBER = UIUtils.dp2px(2);

    public RoundedBackgroundSpan(Context context) {
        super();
        backgroundColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.NavigationBarStrokeColor);
        textColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
        backgroundTranspernt = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent);
    }

    public RoundedBackgroundSpan(Context context, @ColorRes int textColor,
                                 @ColorRes int backgroundColor) {
        super();
        this.backgroundColor = context.getResources().getColor(backgroundColor);
        this.textColor = context.getResources().getColor(textColor);
        backgroundTranspernt = context.getResources().getColor(backgroundColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int
            y, int bottom, Paint paint) {


        paint = new Paint(paint); // make a copy for not editing the referenced paint

        paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);

        // Draw the rounded background
        paint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        float textHeightWrapping = UIUtils.dp2px(0);
        float tagBottom =
                top + textHeightWrapping + PADDING_Y + mTextSize + PADDING_Y + textHeightWrapping;
        float tagRight = x + getTagWidth(text, start, end, paint);
        RectF rect = new RectF(x, top, tagRight, tagBottom);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, CORNER_RADIUS, CORNER_RADIUS, paint);

        // Draw the text
        paint.setColor(textColor);
        canvas.drawText(text, start, end, x + PADDING_X,
                tagBottom - PADDING_Y - textHeightWrapping - MAGIC_NUMBER, paint);

    }

    @Override
    public int getSize(Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt
            fm) {
        paint = new Paint(paint); // make a copy for not editing the referenced paint
        paint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
        return getTagWidth(text, start, end, paint);
    }

    private int getTagWidth(CharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint paint) {
        return Math.round(PADDING_X + paint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, end).toString()) + PADDING_X);
    }

    @Override
    public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end, int i2, int i3,
                             Paint.FontMetricsInt fontMetricsInt) {
        //we need to implement this so the text know the  line height
    }
}
```

**It masks the phone to make it clickable with clickSpan**

[image]

Comment: could you show us your code?

Comment: the stack trace is fully Android source nothing to point to my code.

Comment: there must be some point in code where it is crashing

Comment: ok, if so, can you see any line talking about a package other than Android? can you read the stack trace?

Comment: is that crash on a samsung device with android 8.0? I have the exact same issue.. you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This error relates to text being added to a `TextView`. The rounded backgound you refer to is not relevant, as the error relates specfically to text, not any other aspect of a `TextView`.

The error can occur if the `TextView` is manipulated from a thread other than the main thread. Ensure that any code touching UI widgets is executed only on the main thread. If you are using RxJava ensure that you have properly used `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably some specific characters in your text that android fails to display. Probably some invisible special codes. For example I face the same issue when I have \u200F in my text.

Comment: Can confirm this is just silly, it was crashing because of a "\n" inside my text. Looking for a workaround..

Comment: Okay its was a known bug, combination of spanned text + special characters. Workaround: avoid spans or https://gist.github.com/pyricau/3424004