# How to determine source of crashes in Firebase if no stack frames are from my app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

In some Firebase crash reports, I have crashes where the source is not clear from the data in the Firebase console. For example, if an activity crashed and none of the stack frames appear to be from my app. The stack traces don't provide any useful information.

An example of such a crash in the console:

[image: 1]

The stack trace:

```
android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunCursor (Paint.java:2160)
android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunCursor (Paint.java:2112)
android.widget.Editor.getNextCursorOffset (Editor.java:924)
android.widget.Editor.access$4700 (Editor.java:126)
android.widget.Editor$SelectionEndHandleView.positionAndAdjustForCrossingHandles (Editor.java:4708)
android.widget.Editor$SelectionEndHandleView.updatePosition (Editor.java:4692)
android.widget.Editor$HandleView.onTouchEvent (Editor.java:4012)
android.widget.Editor$SelectionEndHandleView.onTouchEvent (Editor.java:4726)
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:9377)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2554)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2255)
android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (PopupWindow.java:2015)
android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:9597)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4234)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4100)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3699)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3665)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3848)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3699)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3665)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3646)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5926)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:5900)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5861)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6029)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:185)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents (InputEventReceiver.java)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents (InputEventReceiver.java:176)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput (ViewRootImpl.java:6000)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6052)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:858)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:670)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:600)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:844)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:234)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5526)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I'm not sure how to debug this because, as above, the entire stack trace never passes through my app so I have no idea where to look.

Comment: Sometimes a crash can occur simply because the device's version of Android had a bug in it.  Unless it's happening a lot, and on popular devices, it may not be worth addressing.

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be a problem with your XML layout, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/28644616/2592962.

Comment: @WillBeason Yes, I saw that question too. That's why wanted to know where is this coming from.

Comment: Just confirmed - very likely an XML issue. Updating my answer.

Comment: @WillBeason the question is not about particularly this crash. I see a lot of similar crashes like this on Firebase. Some of them a rare and some are not (40 instances in 30 days).

Comment: @WillBeason I also checked my xml layout files for usage of textAllCaps with `EditText`s (`ack "textAllCaps"`), and didn't find anything. So, I think that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @alashow In general, do these crashes represent rendering issues (android.view, android.graphics) which do have stack frames from your Java code? If so, they probably originate from problems with your app's XML.

Comment: @WillBeason no, not necessarily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137086/discussion-between-will-beason-and-alashow).

Comment: What other information would you like in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Per Doug's comment, this does looks like an Android crash and not directly from your app (as none of the stack frames appear to be from your app). This specific issue is a rendering problem as it passes through `android.graphics` and `android.view`, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28644616/2592962). It likely represents a rendering problem originating from your app's XML.

Unfortunately, that is all the information Firebase currently surfaces.

Comment: I know this bug is coming from Android frameworks and not my code itself. But I wanted to know exactly in what part of my app is this crash occurring. This crash specifically is known and has workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849676/

Comment: @alashow I love how it's been known and unfixed for almost five years...